Number of arrangements of flowers such that there aren't three consecutive of the same colour.
Question: We have 7 red flowers and 4 blue flowers. We want to find the number of arrangements of these flowers such that there we do not have 3 consecutive flowers of the same colour.
My Idea: The total number of arrangements is 330 (11 choose 4). Now I wanted to subtract the number of arrangements that have 3 consecutive flowers. My idea was to 'block' flowers for this counting, but I'm struggling since with 7 purple flowers we could have two sets of these blocks, so I'm struggling to count these. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.
Also, if anyone has a book recommendation that deals with counting problems like this it would be very useful for my studies.

I think you’ll find it easiest to put the red flowers in a line and count the possible positions of the blue flowers in the gaps between the red flowers.  I can give an answer when I get back to my desk, but this hint should give you a good start.


Consider the $4$ blue flowers as bars creating $5$ bins, $\square B\square B\square B\square B\square$

There are only two possible valid assignment patterns to bins, $22210$ with $\frac{5!}{3!} = 20$ permutations, and $22111$ with $\frac{5!}{2!3!} = 10$ permutations,  thus answer = $30$ ways

The "normal" method would be to use stars and bars with inclusion-exclusion, but it is hardly worthwhile for such a small problem.



Might help to think of dividing the flowers as an integer equation. That is, we can count solutions of $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 7$$ where each $x_i$ is a non-negative integer. The $x_i$'s will represent the number of red flowers in a row before the next blue flower appears, and any order of flowers can be represented by a solution. One simplification is that if three blue flowers appear in a row, then there must be three red flowers in a row as well. So we can focus on counting the number of arrangements featuring at least three red flowers in a row. That is, we want the number of solutions to the above equation where $x_1 \geq 3$ or $x_2 \geq 3$ or ... $x_5 \geq 3$. To correctly count, you can use the inclusion-exclusion principle. Since you can only have at most two $x_i$'s being $3$ or greater, you only need to count focus on two cases: $x_i \geq 3$ for some $i$, and $x_i,x_j \geq 3$ for some $i$ and $j$.

The answer provided by @true blue anil is correct.  Looking at the problem from the perspective suggested in my comment:
At least $3$ of the $6$ gaps between the $7$ red flowers must be filled with a blue flower.  That is because if only two gaps are filled, the $7$ red flowers are divided into $3$ blocks, and the pigeonhole principle tells us that at least one of the blocks must have at least $3$ red flowers.  There are $2$ remaining cases.
Case 1:  If exactly $3$ of those gaps are used (dividing the blue flowers into $4$ blocks), the blocks must have the sizes $2, 2, 2, 1$ in some order.  There are $4$ possible positions for the block of size $1$.
The three gaps in use each must have at least $1$ blue flower, leaving one blue flower unaccounted for.  That last blue flower can go into any of $5$ positions:  The extreme left, the extreme right, or one of the three already-used gaps.
This case therefore accounts for $4 \cdot 5=20$ combinations.
Case 2:  If $4$ of the $6$ possible gaps are in use, then only $2$ gaps are empty and each filled gap has exactly $1$ blue flower.  There are $\binom 64=15$ possible choices of $4$ gaps.
However, we must eliminate the combinations where two consecutive gaps are empty, because that would result in $3$ consecutive red flowers.  There are $5$ of these "forbidden" combinations.
Therefore, this case accounts for an additional $15-5=10$ "good" combinations.
Adding the $2$ cases, there are $20+10=30$ "good" combinations.
